# Hardware raid on Intel D865GLC

Tags: hardware-raid

Is there a way to to setup hardware raid 1 or 5 on an Intel D865GLC motherboard using ATA/IDE drives?

I am aware of various Linux software raid solutions but I would like to try Hardware raid.
There seems o be a few sata raid drivers for this board but as stated earlier I am looking for something that will work with IDE/ATA

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That board does not have a hardware RAID solution. You can create a RAID volume using the controller built into the board, but it will still be a software RAID, as there is no dedicated XOR processor, dedicated cache, or cache battery.

edit: It looks like creating a RAID volume is only supported with SATA anyway on that board.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/9244/how-do-i-differentiate-fake-raid-from-real-raid) about hardware raid and fake raid. Even if the board supported using it on the ata drives I wouldn't use it over linux software raid.