# VMware ESXi 5 on HP ProLiant DL320 G5

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

Can someone confirm that ESXi5 v.5.1 works on a HP ProLiant DL320 G5. VMWare compatibility matrix shows DL320 G6. If it works, do you use any specific drivers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Sometimes the VMware HCL isn't just about whether something will work, but rather, does it makes sense? This server doesn't make sense...

But, ESXi compatibility really hinges on your array controller and NIC support. The chipset of the [ProLiant DL320 G5](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=12572) is supported. The processors *may* be capable. The NIC is supported. It really depends on whether you have an add-on PCIe Smart Array controller installed. The native **Intel 82801GR** storage controller is a "[*Fake RAID*](https://serverfault.com/questions/9244/how-do-i-differentiate-fake-raid-from-real-raid)" controller, and won't be supported.

The details of your server matter in this case. Do you have more information?

Keep in mind that this is a low-end server... 2 drive slots, 8GB RAM maximum, one CPU... so even if compatible, the utility of this server as an ESXi host is low, given more modern options out there.

Comment: Yes, machine is 6(?)yrs old. I will use it with internal drives only and with ~6 small Linux instances.

Comment: You won't have RAID unless you *add* a RAID controller.

Comment: @PeterMmm I could virtualize that whole server on my _desktop_ and have room to spare. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: It is not always power and RAM, guys. It is the form factor (rack), reliability (2x power supply, RAID (non 82801GR)) and still 1yr maintenance contract . It simple fits the requirements !

Comment: But if ESXi5 is an overkill, I will go with Linux host and VirtualBox ...

Answer (score 3):

It's not on the HCL as you said so you'll never know until you try but the best thing to do is just install it to a USB thumb-drive to see if it works or not, then if you're fine you can install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. I just acquired one. Using esxi v 5.5. This server has a usb port on the inside so I loaded esxi on it. Haven't figured out what i want to do with it yet but at least it loaded the hypervisor.