# ESXi sees RAID1 as two hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, raid, vmware-esxi

The server is Proliant ML330 G6. I've activated the embeded SATA RAID in BIOS. Created 1 logical drive in "Option Rom Configuration for Arrays" in RAID 0+1 that consists of two 1TB drives. So in other words I have 1 TB storage because of RAID1. I tried to install ESXi 5.5.0 on that server, but when I get to the screen where I need to select where to install the ESXi I see those two drives. I can choose one of them.

Shouldn't I see only one RAID1 logical drive?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're using software assisted RAID (aka "[FakeRAID](https://serverfault.com/questions/9244/how-do-i-differentiate-fake-raid-from-real-raid)") and don't have the proper (driver) support for it in ESXi.

Head to VMWare's site and use the [VMWare Compatibility Guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) to determine if your version of ESXi is compatible with your RAID controller.

Here's a similar question from ServerFault, in which the accepted answer notes tha thte RAID controller isn't supported:

- [VMware ESXi 5 on HP ProLiant DL320 G5](https://serverfault.com/questions/538623/vmware-esxi-5-on-hp-proliant-dl320-g5)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the RAID setup wrong.

What you trying to do with Raid as 0+1 is a stripe and a mirror so minimum of four drives are needed, RAID 0 is striped and only requires two drives and RAID 1 is mirrored and only requires two drives.

If you try to set RAID 0+1 on two drives it has probably failed and so you can see each drive.

If RAID is setup correct you are right you will only see one drive during installation.

Comment: I was thinking that too, unless that RAID controller allows for adding drives later

Comment: Yeah bit odd, just go back in to the RAID controller and set it to Raid 1 (I'm guessing you want mirroring). Then try again.

Comment: Should I then forget about RAID and just remove one of the hard drives and install ESXi on a single drive

Comment: I would try to set to RAID 1 there will be an option for it somewhere might have to dig about. Depends on what the setup is really, if its a home lab with no important data then yeah just non-raid it, also if the VM's are going to be held elsewhere like a NAS or SAN then its only the ESXi host its not so important as it can be re-installed in about 20 minutes...

Comment: There's only RAID 1+0 and RAID 0. No RAID 1.

Comment: Strange never seen that before. Is this going to be production server or just a home lab?

Comment: It's just for me to play around with, but I will install some services that will be publicly accessible via Internet. So... it's both?

Comment: But are the VM's going to be on that HD or on a NAS/SAN, etc? They will hold the important data, like I say ESXi is just a quick install if that hard drive was to break.

Comment: VMs on that HD. I guess I'll either install ESXi on single 1TB drive without RAID or install Windows Server 2012 without any VM stuff.

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about the difference between RAID 1, and RAID 0+1 it seems to be purely an HP naming convention. To an HP RAID controller a RAID 0+1 with one pair of mirrored drives is the same as a RAID 1 array. I would probably look at booting from a SmartStart CD and run the HP Array Configuration Utility to see how the array looks in there...logic would dictate it should be the same as doing it via the Option ROM but it's worth a try.